# How should I manage a bunch of Linux logins?

Tags: linux, ssh, login

I've gotten a few Raspberry Pis for various things on top of the handful of other ARM devices I have. I have never had to manage so many logins before. Many of these devices will be on 24/7, one will probably run Nextcloud.  All of my devices run Linux, a mix of Debian and Arch Linux installs.

The question is, what is the best method I should use to manage all of these logins easily and securely?

Comment: How do you connect to these devices? ssh? Have you installed ssh keys? Any reason you can't have the same username on all of the devices?

Comment: Right now I have a local LAN connection and SSH in. There is no reason that I can think of why I couldn't use the same username across all the devices.  I was thinking of using SSH keys and just using a Password manager to hold all of the passwords but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way.

Comment: If you use ssh key(s), why do you need passwords (except maybe for emergencies)? I'd make a single keypair and install the public key on all devices, or maybe a few pairs if finer-grained control is necessary.

Comment: What about the device passwords, the one for root and the one for the non-root user?

Comment: If these were my devices, I normally wouldn't need the passwords, so I'd just put them in some file, possibly encrypted, in a safe place and forget about them until I need them - which would be to re-install keys of something goes wrong, and then forget about them again. But YMMV. You can of course use different keys for the root and non-root user if necessary.

Comment: So I'm guessing you set a long password and store it away somewhere.  If you need root, you just use the ssh key instead to log in as root.   Am I right?

Comment: Exactly. With the keys in the `~/.ssh` directory, they even get used automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using ssh to access the devices, put your ssh public key(s) on the various devices, inside `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (you can use `ssh-copy-id` to copy the keys).

Then edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on every device and (a) disable password login setting `PasswordAuthentication no` and (b) make root login possible only using public keys, by setting `PermitRootLogin without-password` ("without-password" is a bit misleading, it means password login is not permitted).

For console access, depending on the security of your environment (and the security requirements of your devices) you can decide to set different secure passwords for every device and keep them safe in a password manager, or if the environment is very secure and controlled (eg. your home) and you don't have sensitive data to protect, you can set very easy to remember passwords everywhere (knowing that network login using those passwords is **not** possible).

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH server can limit user connections by cross checking that they belong to the allowed users group. This can be useful if you have multiple users of which some should not need to remote with SSH, or you just want the added security for example when running web service or database with separate users to your own.

Sources: Managing Linux User Account Security

https://www.upcloud.com/support/managing-linux-user-account-security/

Comment: What about managing multiple logins across many devices?   These Linux devices are mine and only I should have access to them.